# C# Deserialize JSON without key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I got this JSON through an API, no array. How can I deserialize it into a class?

JSON:

```
{{
  "result": [
    "",
    "FC107D66-CEB7-4A6C-A4D2-70D8B72C6D92"
  ]
}}
```

Tried with this code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
{
....
   var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(authJson); //test 1
   LoginDTO testDeserialize = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<LoginDTO>(obj.ToString()); //test 2
}

    public class LoginDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }      
    }
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: 1. Fix it to make it valid JSON (specifically remove the extra `{` and `}` at the start and the end). 2. Deserialize it.

Comment: You can remove the first and last curly brackets, and you can desterilize the valid JSON with your code.

Comment: removed the first and last bracket but still didn't serialize properly with this code.

Comment: `result` inside the JSON is an array. And it looks like an array of strings. So you class should have a property `public List<string> Result{get;set;}`. It does have names like `Name` and `Token` so you will not get values for them directly.

Comment: yep worked with the list, thanks